# How to import csv file into hive table when it has delimiter value, say comma, as a field value?

Tags: hive

I want to import a csv file into hive table. The csv file is having comma (,) as within a field value. How can we escape it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSV SerDe based on below conditions.

If your fields which has comma are in quoted strings.

```
sam,1,"sam is adventurous, brave"
bob,2,"bob is affectionate, affable"

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE csv_table(name String, userid BIGINT,comment STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
with serdeproperties (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "\""   
  )   
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'location_of_csv_file';
```

If your fields which has comma are escaped as below.

```
sam,1,sam is adventurous\, brave
bob,2,bob is affectionate\, affable

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE csv_table(name String, userid BIGINT, comment STRING)
ROW FORMAT serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
with serdeproperties (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\" 
  )   
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/cloudera/input/csv';
```

In both cases, the output will be as below:

```
hive> select * from csv_table;
OK
sam 1   sam is adventurous
bob 2   bob is affectionate
```